# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, decode

подскажите как переделать код для python 3.7

```
# код на python 2.7

message_len = bin(message_len).lstrip('0b').zfill(4)
class_access = bin(class_access).lstrip('0b').zfill(3)
direct = bin(direct).lstrip('0b')
return str(hex(int('0b' + direct + class_access + message_len, base=2))).lstrip('0x').decode("hex")
```

Ошибка

```
# ошибка на python 3.7

return str(hex(int('0b' + direct + class_access + message_len, base=2))).lstrip('0x').decode("hex")
```

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Используйте binascii.unhexlify

Comment: а если нужен будет encode ?

Comment: @JazMartin binascii.hexlify соответственно

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что у класса str должен быть атрибут decode?

Comment: @Александр, ну, он раньше был, теперь его нет (точнее, он теперь у класса bytes)

Comment: Совет на будущее. То, что у вас написано в `return` - называется лапшекод (или макаронный код) - избегайте этого. Сделайте пару дополнительных шагов и не бойтесь создавать переменные - вас никто не поругает за дополнительные переменные, вы никак не ограничены по их количеству. Зато читать и отлаживать такие монструозные однострочники никому не интересно да и попросту намного сложнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bytes.fromhex()` = `.decode("hex")`

```
return bytes.fromhex(str(hex(int('0b' + direct + class_access + message_len, base=2))).lstrip('0x'))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]